# How to create a map from a list of two item tuples in Elixir

Tags: elixir

What would be an elegant way for converting a list of two item tuples like `[{1,2},{3,4}]` into the map `%{1=>2, 3=>4}`?

Keyword list would be trivial, but what if we have arbitrary keys?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
Enum.into(list, %{})
```

Comment: [`Enum.into/2` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/2)

Comment: This answer was written before `Map.new/1` was [created](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/aebd7e5143dcbe32e33f6ca5cb2374bcc5532789), but `Map.new` is the simplest way (see denis' answer).

Answer (score 34):

`Map` module also supports such lists as a parameter to the `new` function:

```elixir
iex> Map.new([{1, 2}, {3, 4}])
%{1 => 2, 3 => 4}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just got it:

```
list = [{1,2},{3,4}]
themap = for e <- list, into: %{}, do: e
```

Comment: A simpler way: `Enum.into(list, %{})`.

Comment: @bitwalker: if you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Interestingly I *think* that this version just compiles to the same thing as the accepted answer. Not as pretty though.